# gradient is being applied to background instead of text in IE and Firefox

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I've got a CSS gradient set up for some text on a webpage. It works fine for Chrome and Safari but isn't getting applied correctly for IE10, IE11 or Firefox. In those browsers the gradient is getting applied as a background color rather than as a gradient to the text itself.

```
.originals h3, .gradient-text {
    color: #00A3B8;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 800;
    /* Newer Browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(330deg, #00e1ff 0%, #ffeb50 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(330deg, #00e1ff 0%, #ffeb50 100%);
    /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(330deg, #00e1ff 0%, #ffeb50 100%);
    /* Chrome 7+ & Safari 5.03+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #00e1ff), color-stop(1, #ffeb50));
    /* IE10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(330deg, #00e1ff 0%, #ffeb50 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Here's what it looks like in

> Chrome:[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNscI.jpg)
>
> IE:[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBtW2.jpg)
>
> Firefox:[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dKMs.jpg)

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong for those browsers? Any help given is greatly appreciated!

**Updated:** Here's the HTML that the gradient is being applied to:

```
<div class="originals">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h3 class="gradient-text">We make, design, engineer, create, illuminate, record, capture, code, program, open, decide, speak, blend, paint, construct, launch, markup, ignite, form, defend, ink.</h3>
        <img src="/img/myLogo.png" alt="logo" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the ".originals" and ".gradient-text tags" tags?

Comment: @Aydin See the updated markup I provided.

Comment: `-webkit-background-clip: text;` and `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` work only in browsers based on webkit, and do not work in IE and FF

Comment: @fen1x I know that there's a `background-clip: text;` that wirks in IE and Firefox. Is there an alternative to the text-fill-color that I can use?

Comment: @tylerbhughes Not that I know of. Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to a friend of mine who's really good at CSS and he was able to resolve the issue using the following code:

**HTML**

```
<section class="originals">
  <h3 class="gradient-text">We make, design, engineer, create, illuminate, record, capture, code, program, open, decide, speak, blend, paint, construct, launch, markup, ignite, form, defend, ink.</h3>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.gradient-text {
  color: #00e1ff;
}
@supports (mix-blend-mode: lighten) {
  .gradient-text {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  }
 .gradient-text::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(120deg,#00e1ff, #ffeb50);
    background: linear-gradient(120deg,#00e1ff, #ffeb50);
    pointer-events: none;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;

  }
}


/* Page styling, ignore */
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.originals {
  background: #0C2322;
  min-height: 50vh;
  padding: 2em;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

This makes the gradient consistent in both Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. For IE it falls back to a solid cyan color.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
-webkit-background-clip:text
```

and there's your problem. Consult a polyfill at https://codepen.io/TimPietrusky/pen/cnvBk to make work in IE-browsers.